# Delete current command

Tags: ssh, putty, command-history

Is there a keyboard shortcut to delete the current command?

Let's say I have:

```
$ cp /home/one/two/tree/ /var/www/one/two/three
```

I want to easily the current command, specially when it's long and I had a typo. The up and down history selection doesn't remove the current command at all.

Comment: What shell (Bash/ksh/zsh) are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your shell is `bash`, this question has been asked and answered [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679776/how-do-i-clear-delete-the-current-line-in-terminal).

Press <kbd>Ctrl-U</kbd> to delete the command line from the location of the cursor up to the beginning. Precede this by <kbd>Ctrl-E</kbd> if the cursor isn't at the end of the line.

Or press <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> to cancel the current prompt and obtain a new one, which has the benefit that you still see the command you typed.

As bash is highly customizable, the above should work in a default setup, but you or your package provider might always reconfigure the shell for a different set of shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

Try Command Line Editing?

If you are using Bash, check:
http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Line-Editing.html